# Evaluate this limit without LHopital

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

> Using definition of limits, need to find $g'(x)$ for $g(x)= \dfrac{\sin x}{15}$

$g'(x) = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \dfrac{g(c+h) -g(c)}{h} = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{\sin (x+h) - \sin x}{15}}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{ \sin x(\cos h-1) + \sin h \cos x}{15h}$

Since $\;\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \dfrac{ \cos h - 1}{h} = 0$

$\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \sin x ( \sin h \cos x)$

From this, I cannot see how I can get to the final answer of $\;\dfrac{\cos x}{15}\;.\;$ I am doing this without the LHopital rule. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How did you go from $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)(\cos(h)-1) + \sin(h)\cos(x)}{15h}$ to $\lim_{h\to 0} \sin(x)(\sin(h)\cos(x))$ ?

Comment: Also use $\lim_{h\to 0} \sin(h)/h=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{align}
g'(x)&=\lim_\limits{y\to0}\dfrac{g(c+h)-g(c)}h\\[1em]
&=\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\dfrac{\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}{15}}h\\[1em]
&=\lim_\limits{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin x(\cos h-1)+\sin h\cos x}{15h}\\[1em]
&=\lim_\limits{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin x(\cos h-1)}{15h}+\lim_\limits{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h \cos x}{15h}\\[1em]
\end{align}$

$\\$

After applying $\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{\cos h-1}h=0$
, we're left with
$\;\lim_\limits{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h\cos x}{15h}\;$ where you can use
$\;\lim_\limits{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1\;$ to get the answer.

Comment: Why is there still a $h$ in the denominator of $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h \cos x}{15h}$ Since $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \cos h - 1}{h} = 0$ taking the "h" away

Comment: @user307640 edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @KB, good answer, I have upvoted you.

Comment: @user307640 Consider accepting the answer if it indeed answers your question.